# Password policy settings for organisation in Trello

Tags: trello

Is it possible to modify password policy settings (length, ...) for a organisation within trello.com? So if user is part of organisation he has to have an adequate password. If currently this is not possible, are there any plans to implement this feature in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but if you'd like to request this feature, then you can file a feature request at `feature-ideas@trello.com`